# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException with PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have the following code in DAO class:

```
public boolean employeeExists(String employeeCode) throws InstantiationException, SQLException {
    String SQL_TEXT = "select count(*) from employee where emp_code=?;";

    int scalarValue = 0;

    Connection conn = DatabaseAccess.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_TEXT);
    pstmt.setString(1, employeeCode);

    try {
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(SQL_TEXT);
        if (rs.next()) {
            scalarValue = rs.getInt(1);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO: log error.
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (pstmt != null && !pstmt.isClosed())
            pstmt.close();
        if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed())
            conn.close();
    }
    return scalarValue > 0;
}
```

When I run the code i.e invoke the above DAO method, I get the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?'
```

The syntax seems to be ok and executes in mysql workbench but is throwing exception using JDBC.
Is it some kind of bug in mysql jdbc driver? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in :- `ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(SQL_TEXT);`

Change it to :- `ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();`

Answer (score 0):

You already created the `PreparedStatement` with the param that contains the query (SQL_TEXT), you don't need to call it again.

```
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(SQL_TEXT);
```

When you do this, you are executing the `SQL_TEXT` without setting the variable to the `?`, so your query is containing an interrogation mark, that is not recognisable by the MySql. You just have to do:

```
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Because you set the `SQL_TEXT` in

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_TEXT);
```